# How to subset a teradata table in Python

Tags: python, subset, teradata, pyodbc

Help me to run a Teradata query in Python using external criteria please.

I am trying to use pyodbc to run some Teradata query in Python.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
link='driver=xxx; AUTHENTICATION=xxx;DBCNAME=xx;UID=xxx;PWD=xx'
connection=pyodbc.connect(link,autocommit=True)
query='select col1,col2 from table where acct in (12345,67890,etc);'
df=pd.read_sql(query,connection)
```

This runs fine. However, I have a list of account numbers (about 500K) that I need to run this query for and the whole size of the Teradata table is huge and there is no way to pull everything out into python. So my question is how to query a subset of that Teradata table for only these 500K account?

Comment: Do you have those account numbers stored in a table somewhere on your system?  It could be as simple as a sub-select: `WHERE acct IN (SELECT acct_id FROM MyAccountTable)`.

Comment: That really is the only reasonable way to pull this off. You can't submit 500k as an `in-list` in your SQL without blowing way over the SQL character limit (or the parsing engines memory limits) so the only reasonable way is write your 500k list into a table (volatile would be fine) and then query using a JOIN or `IN` condition.